# Hide option of 3rd select list which are selected in 1st and 2nd select list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 select list in which 1st for x axis and 2nd for y axis with common options in all 3 select list
I want to  hide options of 3rd select list which are selected in 1st and 2nd and show remaining
this must happen every time changed the 1st and 2nd select list and show last hidden options.

Please some one help me

```
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6  form-group DropDown1">
                <select class="form-control DropDown" name="DropDown1" id="DropDown1">
                    <option value="">Select Options to Search</option>
                    <option value="11">11</option>
                    <option value="22">22</option>
                    <option value="33">33</option>
                    <option value="44">44</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6  form-group DropDown2">
                <select class="form-control DropDown" name="DropDown2" id="DropDown2">
                    <option value="">Select Options to Search</option>
                    <option value="11">11</option>
                    <option value="22">22</option>
                    <option value="33">33</option>
                    <option value="44">44</option>
                </select>
            </div>


            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                <legend>Advanced Search Options</legend>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4  form-group DropDown3">
                <select class="form-control DropDowns" name="DropDown3" id="DropDown3">
                    <option value="">Select Options to Search</option>
                    <option id="DropDown_opt11" value="opt11">11</option>
                    <option id="DropDown_opt22" value="opt22">22</option>
                    <option id="DropDown_opt33" value="opt33">33</option>
                    <option id="DropDown_opt44" value="opt44">44</option>
                    <option id="DropDown_opt55" value="opt55">55</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

I am hiding with this jquery but when i reselect 1st or 2nd select list option 
last hidden option is not shown its goes on hinding options

```
            var drop2;
            var drop1;
            $(document).ready(function(){

                $('.DropDown1').on('change',"#DropDown1",function(){
                    drop1  = $("#DropDown1 option:selected").val();
                });

                $('.DropDown2').on('change',"#DropDown2",function(){
                    drop2  = $("#DropDown2 option:selected").val();

                });
            });

            $('.DropDown3').click(function(){
                var selector2 = 'DropDown_opt'+drop1;
                var selector3 = 'DropDown_opt'+drop2;
                    $("#"+selector2).hide(selector2);
                    $("#"+selector3).hide(selector3);
            });
```

Comment: instead of hiding just disable them

Comment: Seems to work just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unhide the options that are hidden. I added a function to unhide the previously hidden options.

Check the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/he4wq196/1/

```
function unhideOptions() {
    $('#DropDown3 > option').each(function(){
        $(this).show();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.prop("disabled",true)` to disable the `option` or `.hide()` to hide it.

I've also cleaned your code a bit

```
var drop1, drop2;
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on('change', "#DropDown1,#DropDown2", function() {
    var d = $(this).attr("id").replace("DropDown","drop");
    window[d] = 'DropDown_opt' + $(this).find("option:selected").val();
    hideoptions()
  });
});

function hideoptions() {
  $("#DropDown3 option").prop("disabled", false);
  $("#DropDown3 #" + drop1).prop("disabled", true);
  $("#DropDown3 #" + drop2).prop("disabled", true);
};
```

```js
var drop1, drop2;
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on('change', "#DropDown1,#DropDown2", function() {
    var d = $(this).attr("id").replace("DropDown","drop");
    window[d] = 'DropDown_opt' + $(this).find("option:selected").val();
    hideoptions()
  });
});

function hideoptions() {
  $("#DropDown3 option").prop("disabled", false);
  $("#DropDown3 #" + drop1).prop("disabled", true);
  $("#DropDown3 #" + drop2).prop("disabled", true);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6  form-group DropDown1">
  <select class="form-control DropDown" name="DropDown1" id="DropDown1">
      <option value="">Select Options to Search</option>
      <option value="11">11</option>
      <option value="22">22</option>
      <option value="33">33</option>
      <option value="44">44</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6  form-group DropDown2">
  <select class="form-control DropDown" name="DropDown2" id="DropDown2">
      <option value="">Select Options to Search</option>
      <option value="11">11</option>
      <option value="22">22</option>
      <option value="33">33</option>
      <option value="44">44</option>
  </select>
</div>


<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
  <legend>Advanced Search Options</legend>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4  form-group DropDown3">
  <select class="form-control DropDowns" name="DropDown3" id="DropDown3">
      <option value="">Select Options to Search</option>
      <option id="DropDown_opt11" value="opt11">11</option>
      <option id="DropDown_opt22" value="opt22">22</option>
      <option id="DropDown_opt33" value="opt33">33</option>
      <option id="DropDown_opt44" value="opt44">44</option>
      <option id="DropDown_opt55" value="opt55">55</option>
  </select>
</div>
```